# Sum array of data within date range and other = text

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, sumifs

I have a dataset with two tabs, one with monthly goal(target) and another tab with sales and order data. I'm trying to summarize sales data from the other tab into the target tab using several parameters with an Index(Match and SumIfs:

My Attempt:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(OrderBreakdown!$A$2:$T$8048,,MATCH(C2,OrderBreakdown!$G$2:$G$8048)),OrderBreakdown!$I$2:$I$8048,">="&A2,OrderBreakdown!$I$2:$I$8048,"<="&B2)
```

Order Breakdown is the other sheet, column D in OrderBreakdown sheet is what I want to sum if OrderBreakdown_Category(Col G) = Col C and if OrderBreakdown_Order Date(Col I) >= Start Date(Col A) and if OrderBreakdown_Order Date(Col I) <= End Date(Col A)

My answer should be much more in line with Col D but instead I'm getting $MM

Here's a sample of the dataset I'm pulling from:

dataset I'm pulling from

[image: example Data set]

Comment: do you have an idea on the maximum number of rows you will be dealing with, or are you needing to verify all1 048 576 rows that the excel sheet is capable of handling?  Just asking as I see in your equation that you are referencing to row 8048, but in your general description your are referencing whole column.

Comment: Alex, I had not seen any feedback in the way of marking it correct or not.  Did this get the problem solved for you?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am not sure why your range to sum is from A through T - that is probably where you went wrong.  Also, I did not find the index method necessary.  This should work for you

```
=SUMIFS(OrderBreakdown!$D$2:$D$8048,OrderBreakdown!$I$2:$I$8048, ">=" & A2,OrderBreakdown!$I$2:$I$8048, "<=" & B2, OrderBreakdown!$G$2:$G$8048, "<=" & C2)
```

Here is my sample data Starting on first sheet row 2

```
1/1/2011    1/30/2011    Office Supplies
```

Then the orderBreakdown tab starts on column C

```
Discount    Sales   Profit  Quantity    Category    sub-category    OrderDate
0.5 $45.00  ($26.00)    3    Office Supplies    Paper 1/1/11 Eugene Mo Stockholm Sweden North Home Offic 1/5/11 Second Cla: Stockholm 2011-(11 0.1-2011 2011    1/1/2011
0   $854.00     $290.00     7   Furniture   BookCases   1/2/2011
0   $854.00     $290.00     7   Furniture   BookCases   12/32/2010
```